# How to do multiprocessing in class with self parameter

Tags: python, class, python-multiprocessing, self

### Code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 10

    def main_loop(self):
        while True:
            self.a -= 2
            print(self.a)

    def player_status(self):
        while True:
            self.a -= 5
            print(self.a)
    
    def run(self):
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            Process(target=self.main_loop).start()
            Process(target=self.player_status).start()


a1 = A()
a1.run()
```

However, when I run it, I get 2 different values. - 8 from `main_loop` and 5 from `player_status`.

Why is that?ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Comment: Processes don't share memory. You start with an `A.a = 10`. Then there's two different instances (two different copies of `self`): One that runs in `main_loop` (and does 10 - 2) and another one one that runs `player_status` (and does 10 - 5). Threads do, though.

Comment: So i can do it with threading ? Thank you!

Comment: You can, yes. Keep in mind that threads are subject to [the GIL](https://realpython.com/python-gil/) and could actually slow down your execution. **OR** you could look into how to share data between processes with some sort of shared memory, file, queue... (it's not a trivial issue) Basically both processes will need to agree in some sort of common "thing" where both write and read from.

Comment: @BorrajaX I will use the threading, I don't need that fast execution. Thank you again.